# When has Law Stack Exchange been cited in legal filings?

Tags: any-jurisdiction

I remember seeing one case in which a legal filing of some kind referred to a post on Law Stack Exchange, but I don't remember where it was. What was the document?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I've seen a few recent cases where YouTube law channels have been cited in filings.